# How many users search in English and Hindu on Google India?

Tags: google-search, language

What is the percentage of searches are made in English vs Hindu on Google India?  I could not find stats about it.

(It would be a plus if there are stats on languages too.)

Comment: Questions that are not related to your own website are not on-topic here.   Can you explain how this might effect your website?

Comment: To know how to structure my website (one or two languages) and which language to target.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not release statistics on the number of searches based on languages for a given country coded Google endpoint. Google recommends languages based on your target audience. So if you are wanting to target both Hindi speaking and English speaking users then your best bet it to have your content available in both English and in Hindi using the `hreflag` meta in order to identify the language of your page to Google. With this being done if someone searches using Hindi for a keyword that your site is indexed for then it will try to see if you have a Hindi page for the requested page first and if so will show that in the SERP but if you only have an English page it will provide the user with the option of accessing the page in the English language.